# STM32G030 refuses write to flash

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, cortex-m

The microcontroller throws an error when I'm trying to modify its flash.
[image: The error message]

The memory looks to be unlocked, here is screenshot of option bytes
[image: Option bytes]
[image: Option bytes]

The microcontroller is soldered into a custom board, with power and reset circuit as on the image below.
[image]

What I've tried:

- Initially, the microcontroller was trying to execute instructions from "outside of program code", 0x1fffxxxx range. It happened randomly, the device managed to startup, call HAL_Init, configure clock. I did some switching back and forth with nBOOT0 and nBOOT1 option bytes, and the device started working fine. I did not understand what was the issue and switched them again to try and reproduce the issue. After that the microcontroller refused to write into flash any more...
- I seem to be able to write into WRP1A_STRT and WRP1B_STRT, though it doesn't seem to unlock the flash. WRP2A_STRT and WRP2B_STRT will switch back to 0x00 if I try to modify them. I suspect it's because the device does not have second bank of memory, so it shouldn't affect the flash protection.
- I watched SWDCLK, SWDIO and power pins with an oscilloscope, they look completely healthy.

Interestingly, CubeProgrammer and ST-Link read different data out of the device. Not sure why, and if it's connected to the issue. The data doesn't change over time though.
[image]

Please suggest what may be the issue or what else I could check.

Comment: Maybe you need some kind of pull-up (or down) on the BOOT0 pin. Depending on how you configure the nBOOT bits. See section 2.5 of the [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0454-stm32g0x0-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Comment: The funny thing about this device is that it shares boot0 pin with swclk =) In this case it's supposed to look at option bytes to decide where to boot from. For my combination of option bytes (nBOOT_SEL checked, nBOOT0 checked) it is supposed to boot from flash, which is correct.